# Is there any magic command for Keras version issue?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

In `python`, **TensorFlow** supports magic command to fixed the version used in `Colab or Jupyter Notebook`. Such as, we can use `%tensorflow_version 2.x` to use 2.x TensorFlow or `%tensorflow_version 1.x` to use 1.x TensorFlow version. Similarly, **is there any magic command for Keras version issue?**

Comment: As per my knowledge there is no magic command for `Keras` version. From `Tensorflow V2.3` onwards, `Keras` is integrated in tensorflow and can be imported as `tf.keras`.

Comment: @TFer2 Thank you for your response. But I trained my model in `Keras`. So I need to use the `same version of Keras to load the pre-trained weight`.